# Retrieve process network usage (since restart, if neccessary) via Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I've been hunting for a while on how to get the network usage of a process in Linux using a Bash script, but I've only found the same answers repeated over and over again.

It'd be nice if there was a way to **programamatically** retrieve the network usage of a process, instead of having some poor tech stare at a terminal 24/7 running an instance of *ntop*.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: there is a more or less the same question on serverfault [here][1]



  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/36586/linux-monitor-network-i-o-per-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I've come across is:

cat /proc/PID/net/dev

However, it's not accurate and reports statistics from the whole system.  (virtually identical to /proc/net/dev

Comment: Wow, this is an old question - this answer seems to be the closest to anything we'll find, so I'll mark it as Accepted. Thanks!

Comment: yeah i been trying to find the same thing and this looks like its the best thing I am able to find.